# Count Down Timer app has issue when I change orientation

Tags: android

The layout of my app contains a TextView and a toggle Button. When the toggle Button is turned ON an AlertDialog appears and the user is prompted to give the time for the countdown to start. It works fine if I dont change the orientation while it counts down. However when I change orientation while the countdown keeps running the Dialog Box reappears which shouldn't. I know that changing orientation destroys and recreates my activity so given the fact that toggle button was ON before the activty is destroyed when it is recreated it continuous to be ON as it should be. So my question is if there is a way for the AlertDialog not to appear after the orientation change.

I have tried adding the following but it didnt work
Declared as class variable

```
public static final String  TOGGLE_BUTTON_STATE = "OFF";
```

Trying to set the toggle Button to true

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: created.............");
        mTextTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        if((savedInstanceState != null) && TOGGLE_BUTTON_STATE.equals("ON")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: created after changing orientation........");
            mToggleButton.setChecked(true);
        }
        mToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

saving the state before it is destroyed

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if(mToggleButton.isChecked()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: toggleButton is checked...........****");
        outState.putString(TOGGLE_BUTTON_STATE, "ON");
    }else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: toggleButton is not checked...........*****");
        outState.putString(TOGGLE_BUTTON_STATE, "OFF");
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
```

}

```
   //Listener for the ToggleButton
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            TOGGLE_BUTTON_ON = true;
            //getting the xml user_input to java
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_input, null);
            //search inside the view for the text_input
            mTextUserInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.text_input);
            //We create the builder and we use it to add functionality to the dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Please Enter The Time");
            //We create the user_input that has only the editext widget that we gonna use to get the
            //time from the user
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
            builder.show();
        } else {
            // OFF selected and timer must stop
//            TOGGLE_BUTTON_ON = false;
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
```

ps The countdown timer keeps running properly even after orientation change

Comment: Can you edit the question and paste the alert dialog code?

Comment: Question is edited

Comment: you can prevent your activity from being destroyed after screen orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of loading the previously stored state in `onCreate` is false. You are saving the state correctly (but i would prefer storing it as a boolean) - but you are not reading it correctly from the savedInstance.

The way i would do it:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("TOGGLE_BUTTON_STATE", mToggleButton.isChecked());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        mToggleButton.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("TOGGLE_BUTTON_STATE"));
    }
    mToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer worked with a small change. Setting  the outState must be before calling super method

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss the alert dialog when the activity is going to be destroyed.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    ...
    // Save the dialog in an instance variable
    mDialog = builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (mDialog != null) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```